# Laravel Eloquent find most similar relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

so I'm trying to write an eloquent query, where I find similar models.

Let's say, I have three models ModelA and they have a 1:n relation to the model ModelB.

1. ModalA 1 relation to ModelB a,b,c
2. ModelA 2 relation to ModelB a,d,e
3. ModelA 3 relation to ModelB a,c,e

I would like to make a simple query, where som thing like this happens with ModelA 1:

```
// pseudo code
$model->getMostSimilarRelations('modelBs') // = ModelA 3 --> because 2 relations similar found
```

So I was thinking, there is maybe a way like:

```
// pseudo code
$similars = ModelA::whereHas('modalBs', ['at_least_matching', 1, $relation_ids ])->get();
```

The best case would be, to return the count of the matching realtions, like:

```
[
'modalA' => ['id' => 3, 'hits' => 2],
'modalA' => ['id' => 2, 'hits' => 1],
]
```

Since I don't want to loop manually through all possible relations, I wonder if there is a Eloquent way to solve this? I'm using Laravel since many years, but I never saw something in that way. But maybe I was just missing it.

I appreciate any idea on this.

Comment: Why don't you use `whereHas` and `like` clause in ORM query ? Let's say something like this: `DB::table('foo')->where('bar', 'like', '%baaz%')->get();`

Comment: I thought, like is something to go to, if I want to find a part of a string like a word in a title. What I want to achieve here, is getting multiple same relations to a given array of ids. How would you achieve this with your solution?